# Why does multiple GET requests fail protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I'm trying to run a protractor test in Amazon EC2 environment using the PhantomJS browser. I know it isn't adviced to user PhantomJS with Protractor but it is the only choice I've got right now. The tests always work in Win7 environment.

When the test looks like this it always works fine

```
    describe('Portal Login End 2 End test', function() {
    it('should automatically redirect to login /form', function() {
        browser.get('');
        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/login");
    });

    it('should automatically redirect to dashboard page after successful login', function() {
        element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.buttonText('Sign in')).click();
        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("dashboard/home");
    });
});
```

but when a GET request is made in the beforeEach function like this

```
    describe('Portal Login End 2 End test', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('');
    }
    it('should automatically redirect to login', function() {
        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/login");
    });

    it('should automatically redirect to dashboard page after successful login', function() {
        element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.buttonText('Sign in')).click();
        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("dashboard/home");
    });
});
```

the tests fails most of the time, but not always, with the following error

> UnknownError: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>   Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
>   System info: host: 'ip-10-249-98-182', ip: '10.249.98.182', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
>   Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver

So when **two** GET requests are made in the same test it most often fails, but when only one request is made it always work. And as I wrote above, two GET requests works fine in Win7 environment but not in Linux.

I've seen some posts with this error but not how to fix it. Anyone out there with the solution?

Comment: same error here.. And having difficulties fixing it..

Answer (score 0):

If you're problem, as you said, is because the browser isn't waiting for the get in the beforeEach, add browser.waitForAngular();

```
describe('Portal Login End 2 End test', function() {
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('');
}
it('should automatically redirect to login', function() {
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/login");
});

it('should automatically redirect to dashboard page after successful login', function() {
    element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('admin');
    element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('admin');
    element(by.buttonText('Sign in')).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("dashboard/home");
});
});
```

because the it tests run in order, you shouldn't have to call it in each it block.

you can also try calling browser.waitForAngular() in the beforeEach function, though I prefer to make the call in the it function.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the `beforeEach()` completes the set events in the expected manner, before jumping into any of the `it` sections, is by using the power of, `done()` function, a feature that was included in Jasmine2.0. This was specifically designed to verify that a given event was triggered and that it resulted in the expected action.
In your code, `browser.get('')` is an asynchronous process. You need to `await` all such asynchronous event triggers & confirm once it is `done()`.

Rule of thumb is to use it whenever there is an asynchronous processing.In the coding best practices while writing your test scripts, `done()` function is always passed to the `beforeEach()`, `afterEach()`, and `it()` test methods as an argument, whether you need it or not.

How do you implement this in your code?

```
describe('Portal Login End 2 End test', function() {
beforeEach(function(done) {
    browser.get('');
    success: function () {
      done();
    }
}
it('should automatically redirect to login', function() {
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/login");
});

it('should automatically redirect to dashboard page after successful login', function() {
    element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('admin');
    element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('admin');
    element(by.buttonText('Sign in')).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("dashboard/home");
});
});
```

hope this helps, cheers!